# Where to get JSON Schema for EOS endpoints api?

Tags: nodeos, keosd

Where to get JSON Schema for EOS API endpoints ?

Answer (score 2):

The RPC Api params for all EOS API endpoints are defined in the docs:

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference

---

For example the get account POST request would look like this:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_account',
  body: { account_name: 'eosio' }, // JSON
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

---

Scatter's API endpoint which load balance across many APIs:

```
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get info

cleos -u http://nodes.get-scatter.com:80 get info
```